# How to extend the tinymce validation rules for the style tag?

Tags: tinymce

I have a tinyMCE editor. In that editor I want to enable the user to use an upper cased keyword inside the style tag or any html element, e.g. [COLOR]. The issue is that the editor converts it to lower case, which means that the system cannot identify it later in order to replace it. How can I prevent the editor to edit the keyword?

I tried with external_valid_elements, but it didn't work.

```
extended_valid_elements: "*[style]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by replacing the lower-cased version of the keyword with an upper case before sending it to the back-end.